# How to groupby with custom function in python cuDF?

Tags: rapids, cudf

I am new to using GPU for data manipulations, and have been struggling to replicate some of the functions in cuDF. For instance, I want to get a mode value for each group in the dataset. In Pandas it is easily done with custom functions:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2],
                   'value': [10, 10, 30, 20, 20, 10, 30]}

| group | value |
| ----- | ----- |
| 1     | 10    |
| 2     | 10    |
| 2     | 30    |
| 1     | 20    |
| 3     | 20    |
| 1     | 10    |
| 2     | 30    |

def get_mode(customer):
    freq = {}
    for category in customer:
        freq[category] = freq.get(category, 0) + 1
    key = max(freq, key=freq.get)
    return [key, freq[key]]

df.groupby('group').agg(get_mode)

| group | value |
| ----- | ----- |
| 1     | 10    |
| 2     | 30    |
| 3     | 20    |
```

However, I just can't seem to be able to replicate the same functionality in cuDF. Even though there seems to be a way to do it, of which I have found some examples, but it somehow doesn't work in my case. For example, the following is the function I tried to use for cuDF:

```py
def get_mode(group, mode):
    print(group)
    freq = {}
    for i in range(cuda.threadIdx.x, len(group), cuda.blockDim.x):
        category = group[i]
        freq[category] = freq.get(category, 0) + 1
    mode = max(freq, key=freq.get)
    max_freq = freq[mode]
    
df.groupby('group').apply_grouped(get_mode, incols=['group'],
                                   outcols=dict((mode=np.float64))
```

Can someone please help me understand what is going wrong here, and how to fix it? Attempting to run the code above throws the following error (hopefully I managed to put it under the spoiler):

Error code

```
TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
No implementation of function Function(<function impl_get at 0x7fa8f0500710>) found for signature:

>>> impl_get(DictType[undefined,undefined]<iv={}>, int64, Literal[int](0))

There are 2 candidate implementations:
    - Of which 1 did not match due to:
    Overload in function 'impl_get': File: numba/typed/dictobject.py: Line 710.
      With argument(s): '(DictType[undefined,undefined]<iv=None>, int64, int64)':
     Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
       TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
     non-precise type DictType[undefined,undefined]<iv=None>
     During: typing of argument at /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typed/dictobject.py (719)
     
     File "../../opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typed/dictobject.py", line 719:
         def impl(dct, key, default=None):
             castedkey = _cast(key, keyty)
             ^

raised from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1086
    - Of which 1 did not match due to:
    Overload in function 'impl_get': File: numba/typed/dictobject.py: Line 710.
      With argument(s): '(DictType[undefined,undefined]<iv={}>, int64, Literal[int](0))':
     Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
       TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
     non-precise type DictType[undefined,undefined]<iv={}>
     During: typing of argument at /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typed/dictobject.py (719)
     
     File "../../opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typed/dictobject.py", line 719:
         def impl(dct, key, default=None):
             castedkey = _cast(key, keyty)

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.core.types.containers.DictType'>, 'get') for DictType[undefined,undefined]<iv={}>)
During: typing of call at /tmp/ipykernel_33/2595976848.py (6)


File "../../tmp/ipykernel_33/2595976848.py", line 6:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

During: resolving callee type: type(<numba.cuda.compiler.Dispatcher object at 0x7fa8afe49520>)
During: typing of call at <string> (10)


File "<string>", line 10:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuDF builds on top of Numba's CUDA target to enable UDFs. This doesn't support using a dictionary in the UDF, but you your use case can expressed with built-in operations with pandas or cuDF by combining `value_counts` and `drop_duplicates`.

```py
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'group': [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2],
        'value': [10, 10, 30, 20, 20, 10, 30]
    }
)
​
out = (
    df
    .value_counts()
    .reset_index(name="count")
    .sort_values(["group", "count"], ascending=False)
    .drop_duplicates(subset="group", keep="first")
)
print(out[["group", "value"]])
   group  value
4      3     20
1      2     30
0      1     10
```

Comment: Do I get it correctly that cuDF have not implemented the value_counts() option yet, or am I confusing it with something? It's just that while the solution works fine in Pandas, it gives "AttributeError: DataFrame object has no attribute value_counts" when I try to apply it with cuDF.

Comment: It looks like `DataFrame.value_counts` was recently implemented in the current development branch. You can use this by installing the current 22.08 nightly at https://rapids.ai/start.html

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but I found a workaround for mode. It isn't the best way, doesn't use GPU, and can be quite slow.

```
import pandas as pd
import cudf

df = cudf.DataFrame({'group': [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2],
                   'value': [10, 10, 30, 20, 20, 10, 30]}

df.to_pandas().groupby('group').agg({'value':pd.Series.mode})
```

Comment: That's how I was initially doing it - moving from cuDF to Pandas, getting the mode there and moving back to cuDF. The sad thing is, cuDF is so fast in comparison that this workaround was essentially doubling the time spent on the whole pipeline.